# Chrome Frame not triggering in IE9 on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, internet-explorer-9, google-chrome-frame

I have installed Chrome Frame and it works on some sites but not on mine. I have the correct code from the Chrome tag site

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1" />
<!--[if IE]><script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/chrome-frame/1/CFInstall.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
```

WHAT AM I DOING WRONG?????????

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen this behaviour before, but I will take a guess:

IE has a config setting which tells it to turn on compatibility mode for local intranet sites (that is, sites on your local network, which would include if you're running your site on your PC for testing). This setting is often defaulted to being switched on, without the user realising it.

The setting triggers IE to override any `X-UA-Compatible` tags in the site, and always force the site into compatibility mode.

This may be causing it to also override your Chrome Frame mode.

So check your browser settings, and if you have this flag switched on, turn it off and try again.

Bear in mind that if your site is for use on an internal network, then this flag may be set for most or all your users. (and if it's for an external site, then bear in mind that most users won't have Chrome Frame installed!)

Answer (score 1):

Is this meta tag [within the 1024 first bytes in the document](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=23003)?